# Vaadin Flow Notification with a modal Dialog

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

### Summary

When a Vaadin Flow Notification is showing, opening a modal Dialog prevents the Notification from handling click events, even though the Notification is in front of (i.e. higher z-index) the Dialog.

### Example

With the sample code below (used with a Vaadin 23.3.4 Starter project),

1. Click 'Show Notification' Button
2. Click 'Show Dialog' Button
3. Try to close the Notification

It is not possible to close the Notification until the Dialog has been closed, which is very confusing for the user.

```
@Route("notification")
public class NotificationView extends VerticalLayout {

  public NotificationView() {

    // Create the notification
    Notification notification = new Notification();
    notification.addThemeVariants(NotificationVariant.LUMO_ERROR);
    notification.setPosition(Position.MIDDLE);
    Div text = new Div(new Text("Some error notification!"));
    Button closeButton = new Button(new Icon("lumo", "cross"), e -> notification.close());
    closeButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY_INLINE);
    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout(text, closeButton);
    layout.setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
    notification.add(layout);

    // Create a modal dialog
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.setHeaderTitle("Test Dialog");
    dialog.setCloseOnOutsideClick(false);
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.setDraggable(true);
    dialog.setHeight(400, Unit.PIXELS);
    dialog.setWidth(600, Unit.PIXELS);
    Paragraph paragraph =
        new Paragraph(
            "This is a modal dialog that can be dragged and that can show a notification.");
    Button notificationFromDialogButton = new Button("Show Notificaion", e -> notification.open());
    Button closeDialogButton = new Button("Close", e -> dialog.close());
    VerticalLayout dialogLayout =
        new VerticalLayout(paragraph, notificationFromDialogButton, closeDialogButton);
    dialog.add(dialogLayout);

    // Add buttons to launch notification and dialog
    addClassName("centered-content");
    add(
        new Button("Show Notification", e -> notification.open()),
        new Button("Show Dialog", e -> dialog.open()));
  }
}
```

Lowering the z-index of the `vaadin-notification-container` will ensure that the Dialog is shown in front of the Notification, but this will now mean that a Notification launched by the Dialog will be hidden behind the Dialog.

### Questions

This seems like a bug in Vaadin, but regardless I am interested in a workaround. Is it possible to prevent the Dialog's modal curtain from swallowing the Notification's click event? What other options are there?

### Update

Just to be clear, the user is presented with the following, and cannot close the Notification despite it being clearly in front of the Dialog. The only way out of this situation is for them to click 'Close' on the Dialog.

[image]

Comment: This is intentional. Dialog is modal, so it must block the Notification that was opened before the Dialog. If Notification is opened after the Dialog, it will not be blocked by the modal curtain.

Comment: @TatuLund Thank you very much for your response. I have updated my question with a screenshot just to be clear. Unfortunately, this is not acceptable user experience for us. Was hoping for a workaround.

Comment: Dialog.setModal(false)